# Show hidden select menus if value of another select menu is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to jQuery and javaScript. I am using bootstrap. I have a select menu that is visible and two additional select menus that are hidden. I would like to show the hidden select menus id the user selects "TV" from the visible select menu options. If they select any of the other value options from the visible select menu, I need to display a simple text box where they can explain. After researching online I attempted to do it using some js, but it is not working. Below is my code and here is my jsfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/nx6cc1Lc/

HTML:

```
<div class="hear-from">
      <div class="selects-4 col-xs-12">
          <label for="heard_tv">Where did you hear about us from?</label>
                <select id="heard_tv" class="form-control selectTV" name="heard_tv">
                     <option>--Choose Option--</option>
                     <option value="TV">TV Commercial</option>
                     <option value="Radio">Radio Advertisement-Other</option>
                     <option value="OT">Other</option>
                </select>
     </div>
     <div class="selects-5 col-xs-6 hidden">
                <select id="heard_from_station" class="form-control selectStation" name="heard_from_station">
                     <option>--Choose Station--</option>
                     <option value="TV:ABC">ABC News</option>
                     <option value="TV:TWCNews">New York 1 - TWC News</option>
                     <option value="TV:BBC">BBC America</option>
                     <option value="TV:CNBC">CNBC</option>
                     <option value="TV:CNN">CNN</option>
                     <option value="TV:Fox News">FOX News</option>
                     <option value="TV:Fox Business">FOX Business</option>
                     <option value="TV:TWCNews">Time Warner News</option>
                     <option value="TV:HLN">Headline News</option>
                     <option value="TV:MSNBC">MSNBC</option>
                     <option value="TV:Other">Other</option>
                </select>
          </div>

          <div class="selects-6 col-xs-6 hidden">
                <select id="heard_from_provider" class="form-control selectProvider" name="heard_from_provider">
                     <option>--Choose Provider--</option>
                     <option value="TVP:ATT">AT & T</option>
                     <option value="TVP:Comcast">Comcast</option>
                     <option value="TVP:Cablevision">Cablevision</option>
                     <option value="TVP:Charter">Charter Comm.</option>
                     <option value="TVP:Cox">Cox Comm.</option>
                     <option value="TVP:DirectTV">DirectTV</option>
                     <option value="TVP:Dish">Dish Network</option>
                     <option value="TVP:TimeWarner">Time Warner Cable</option>
                     <option value="TVP:VerFiOS">Verizon FiOS</option>
                     <option value="TVP:Antenna">Over the Air / Antenna</option>
                     <option value="TVP:Other">Other TV Provider</option>
                 </select>
             </div>

     </div>
```

Javascript:

```
// show tv station and provider menus if TV selected
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#heard_tv').on('change', function() {
          if ( this.value === "TV")
          //.....................^.......
          {
            $("#heard_from_station").removeClass('hidden');
            $("#heard_from_provider").removeClass('hidden');
          }
          else
          {
            $('#heard_from_station').removeClass().addClass('hidden');
            $('#heard_from_provider').removeClass().addClass('hidden');
          }

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your script as given below.

```
// show tv station and provider menus if TV selected
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#heard_tv').on('change', function() {
          if ( this.value === "TV")
          {
            $("#heard_from_station").parent().removeClass('hidden');
            $("#heard_from_provider").parent().removeClass('hidden');
          }
          else
          {
            $('#heard_from_station').parent().addClass('hidden');
            $('#heard_from_provider').parent().addClass('hidden');
          }

        });

    });
```

As your html contains "hidden" class on the parent element ".parent()", you need to add / remove class on the parent. Alternatively, you can also give ID to the parent elements and use those ids directly in your script, without using ".parent()".

Answer (score 0):

Just use show() and hide() of jquery for this.Below is the code part for your issue

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="sample.js"></script>

   <div class="hear-from">
                                            <div class="selects-4 col-xs-12">
                                                <label for="heard_tv">Where did you hear about us from?</label>
                                                    <select id="heard_tv" class="form-control selectTV" name="heard_tv">
                                                        <option>--Choose Option--</option>
                                                        <option value="TV">TV Commercial</option>
                                                        <option value="Radio">Radio Advertisement-Other</option>
                                                        <option value="OT">Other</option>
                                                     </select>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="selects-5 col-xs-6" style="display:none">
                                                    <select id="heard_from_station" class="form-control selectStation" name="heard_from_station">
                                                        <option>--Choose Station--</option>
                                                        <option value="TV:ABC">ABC News</option>
                                                        <option value="TV:TWCNews">New York 1 - TWC News</option>
                                                        <option value="TV:BBC">BBC America</option>
                                                        <option value="TV:CNBC">CNBC</option>
                                                        <option value="TV:CNN">CNN</option>
                                                        <option value="TV:Fox News">FOX News</option>
                                                        <option value="TV:Fox Business">FOX Business</option>
                                                        <option value="TV:TWCNews">Time Warner News</option>
                                                        <option value="TV:HLN">Headline News</option>
                                                        <option value="TV:MSNBC">MSNBC</option>
                                                        <option value="TV:Other">Other</option>
                                                     </select>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="selects-6 col-xs-6" style="display:none">
                                                    <select id="heard_from_provider" class="form-control selectProvider" name="heard_from_provider">
                                                        <option>--Choose Provider--</option>
                                                        <option value="TVP:ATT">AT & T</option>
                                                        <option value="TVP:Comcast">Comcast</option>
                                                        <option value="TVP:Cablevision">Cablevision</option>
                                                        <option value="TVP:Charter">Charter Comm.</option>
                                                        <option value="TVP:Cox">Cox Comm.</option>
                                                        <option value="TVP:DirectTV">DirectTV</option>
                                                        <option value="TVP:Dish">Dish Network</option>
                                                        <option value="TVP:TimeWarner">Time Warner Cable</option>
                                                        <option value="TVP:VerFiOS">Verizon FiOS</option>
                                                        <option value="TVP:Antenna">Over the Air / Antenna</option>
                                                        <option value="TVP:Other">Other TV Provider</option>
                                                     </select>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>

 <script>   $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#heard_tv').on('change', function() {
          if ( this.value === "TV")
          //.....................^.......
          {
            $(".selects-5").show();
            $(".selects-6").show();
          }
          else
          {
            $('.selects-5').hide();
            $('.selects-6').hide();
          }

        });

    });</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `div` tags that contain your secondary select menus are hidden, not the select menus themselves -- even so, your script is trying to remove the class from the select menus. So there are a number of ways you can fix this.

One way to fix this is to apply the hidden class to your select menus instead of your `div` tags.

```
<div class="selects-5 col-xs-6">
    <select id="heard_from_station" class="form-control selectStation hidden" name="heard_from_station">
                 ...
    </select>
</div>

<div class="selects-6 col-xs-6">
    <select id="heard_from_provider" class="form-control selectProvider hidden" name="heard_from_provider">
                 ...
    </select>
</div>
```